# Allow Auto lock in my app on iphone Sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to allow auto lock to when my app is active..!

I am trying lot of code's from internet...!,all code's does not work.

I am try Below Code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
```

But,code does not work, this code try the view controller **viewdidload** event..!,

But Screen is always on in my app,My app is active does not allow auto lock.

My iphone set auto lock time in 1 minute...!

any one help with us..!

Thanks..!

Comment: Is your phone attached to the computer and are you debugging? Try without debugger & cable!

Comment: Yes check debugging and i am check remove cable from computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you run your application without debugger and without being connected to computer with the USB cable. When you use the debugger the phone lock will be never activated.